# What is the number of functions $f$ from the set $\{1, 2, . . . , 2n\}$ to $\{1, 2, . . . , n\}$ so that $f(x) \leq \lceil x/2 \rceil$ for all $x$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

What is the number of functions $f$ from the set $\{1, 2, . . . , 2n\}$ to $\{1, 2, . . . , n\}$ so that $f(x) \leq \lceil x/2 \rceil$ for all $x$?

I'm a complete beginner at solving something like this, and I tried to use the product rule. I'm 99% sure I've done it wrong.

So for elements $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8$, there are $1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4$ possibilities respectively (if I'm understanding this right)

If this continues for element $2n$ there will be $n$ possibilities. I'm not sure how to continue to how many functions there are from here. If I had to guess since there are $1/2$ as many possibilities as the element number.

There are $n^{m}$ functions from $m$ elements to $n$ elements so would the answer be $\frac{n^{m}}{2}$ ? Is my logic correct?

Comment: This is equivalent to the accepted answer but with a different presentation: The number of possibilites (and you _almost_ got there) $=1 \times 1 \times 2 \times 2 \times 3 \times 3 \times \cdots \times n \times n$, which can be easily rearranged into $(1\times 2\times \cdots \times n) \times (1\times 2\times \cdots \times n) = (n!)^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you state in your question, there is $1$ place the value $1$ can map to. 
There is $1$ place that $2$ can map to.

There is $i$ place that $2i-1$ can map to & $i$ places that $2i$ can map to.

So there will be $\color{red}{(n!)^2}$ such mappings.

Comment: Could you explain how you got n!? I though that there were n! possibilities if possibilities kept decreasing by 1 for each element. i.e Element 1, 2, 3 , n would have n, n-1, n-2,  n! possibilities respectively. I'm not sure how n! works in this case

Comment: Edit- Actually I may be understanding, is correct to say that for all even elements there are n! mappings. Then for all the odd elements since they map the same way there are also n! mappings. Thus $(n!)^{2}$

Comment: Yeah, That would be another way to see it. $n!$ for the odd elements & $n!$ for the even elements. See figure $1$ here https://oeis.org/A110501/a110501.pdf